# Challenging series with cosine, sine and a variable to be expressed as a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

In my research work, the following two series come out describing the 1st and 2nd order of a physical phenomenon:

$$\mathfrak{f}_1(\alpha )=2\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \ 
    \begin{cases}
      \displaystyle\frac{1}{64k^2}, & |k|=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\alpha}\\
      \displaystyle\frac{\cos(\alpha\pi k)^2}{4(\pi k)^2((2\alpha k)^2-1)^2}, & |k|\neq\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\alpha}
    \end{cases}  , $$

$$\mathfrak{f}_2(\alpha )=2\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}     \begin{cases}
      \displaystyle\frac{9}{256\pi^2k^4}, & |k|=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\alpha} \\
      \displaystyle\left( \frac{\alpha\sin(\alpha\pi k)}{2(\pi k)((2\alpha k)^2-1)}+
      \displaystyle\frac{(3(2\alpha k)^2-1)\cos(\alpha\pi k)}{2(\pi k)^2((2\alpha k)^2-1)^2} \right)^2, & |k|\neq\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\alpha}\\
    \end{cases} , $$

where $0\leq\alpha\leq1$.

These functions look actually much simpler when plotting them and I could determined thanks to a previous post that:

$$ \mathfrak{f}_1(\alpha )=\alpha^2 \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{\pi^2}\right)-\frac{\alpha}{8}+\frac{1}{12} $$

Do you have any idea if it is possible to obtain the polynomial form of $\mathfrak{f}_2(\alpha )$ from $\mathfrak{f}_1(\alpha )$ since they look very close to each other? This would avoid an awfully complicated calculations. Thank you so much!

Comment: Which post, please ?

Comment: This post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4257183/963295

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link.

Comment: You could try wolfram residue e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue+sin%28x%29%2F%28x*%28%282*x%29%5E2-1%29%29